# Repair parts from Shimano - What are these part for?

Tags: shimano, repair, parts

I got a new Cannondale bike with hydraulic disc brakes and Tiagra set from Shimano. With the bike came seom parts which I cannot identify. I think they have to do with the brakes, but can't find anything. The yellow bit says Shimano on it, but thats it.

Any ideas what are these parts for?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The yellow block is a 'bleed block' which is a spacer which replaces the brake pads when bleeding brakes to keep the pads away from oil and to avoid over filling the system.

The white cylinder with o-ring is a funnel extension, which makes a funnel compatible with your road levers when bleeding the brakes (mtb levers don't need it).

The two metal pieces are often known as connector inserts, or barbs, which go inside the hydraulic hose when installing brakes or shortening hydraulic hose. They are essential to prevent crushing the hose. These are just spares. They would normally be found alongside brass olives which are also required to do these tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will search for a manual/guide for my breaks now 

Comment: @loremmonkey you should find a manual, Shimano have them all on their tec docs site, though hopefully you won't need to do any major work on the bike, using these pieces, for a good while yet

Answer (score 4):

Yellow plastic object is a block that is inserted into the caliper to keep the pistons apart when bleeding the brakes. The white cylinder is likely related to bleeding brakes also.